Slack Bot - warning sign on button click saying operation timed out or app took too long to respond
I have created a slack bot application. The service which handles the interaction is written in node js. For the user interactions I am using @slack/interactive-messages to handle the button clicks. Below is the code example
const slackInteractions = createMessageAdapter(slackSigningSecret, {
  syncResponseTimeout: 3000,
});
app.use("/slack/actions", slackInteractions.expressMiddleware());    
slackInteractions.action(
        { actionId: "mainBtnAction" },
        async (payload, respond) => {
          myFunction(payload, payload.actions[0].value, respond)
            .catch(console.error);
          return Promise.resolve(true);
        }
      );

Though this code is working fine, sometimes I get the warning sign on the button click with the tooltip "Operation timed out.." or "this app took too long to respond". I am aware that in slack bot the response should be sent within 3 seconds. Hence I have written my code inside an asynchronous function and returning the Promise on the next line, but still sometimes I get this warning sign.

Sending the text message using respond method is not an option for me, as I want to display a modal form on this button click. I tried opening the popup first with text 'Loading' and then I am updating this popup. This has minimize the frequency of this warning sign, but I am getting it inconsistently.
Is there any other approach to handle this or can I increase the expected response time?
